# Google Maps API V3- Adding listener on markers after they are created

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I got a problem. I am making a map where you can add markers, polylines and polygons using "tools". Like MS Paint and tools there. You click on tool, and then do whatever you want on map.

The thing is, I am adding markers without any listeners, so I can't click them - because I want that tool just to put marker in chosen place.

And my problem is to create a tool, which would let me to delete these markers. But to do that, my tool would need to add click event listener to markers.. and they were created some time ago. Is that possible? Because when I try just to make addeventlistener (marker, 'click, xxx()) i get the error that marker is not defined.

I wont post whole  code here, because its a lot of it, but if you need any part, just ask, I will post it ASAP.

EDIT1:

As Majid Fouladpour said, global variable works but only for last added marker :o?

Comment: whenever the page loads, you loop through all markers and add listeners to each one of them

Comment: Well, i am trying to make refresh-less site. I use ajax to send markers to database, and everything else without refreshing. Thats why i am looking for solution. I am adding every marker from database during page load, and then, i want to add that listener, only if user picks that one tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `marker` a global variable. You are defining it inside a function now:

```
function somefunction(params) {
    ...
    var marker = ....
    ...
}
```

Instead, you should have:

```
var marker;
...

function somefunction(params) {
    ...
    marker = ....
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your comment shows you are now getting the reference part right. If your function is not fired, you should be having an issue in your add listener part of the code. Are you doing it this way?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    alert('x');
});
```

Comment: Hmm, something is still not working, i made a simple site, just map with 4 markers without evenListener, and then try to add that listener to them. When i had that variable defined in function i had the error its not defined, but when i put it in top of everything, i just dont get any error message, and still its not working. Tried just to pop up "alert('x');" after clicking on it... didnt show up.

Comment: It does work, for last added marker only, i would need to use other "marker" variable, for every marker. so i could refer to every single of it. and i want them all to get that listener, so i can pick whichever i want marker to delete

Comment: For multiple markers you need to have a `markers` array. So you define an empty global array `var markers = [];` outside functions, and where you add each marker to the map you should also push it to the array. Then you can manipulate each marker from the array like `markers[n]`. For more specific help you need to add code snippets to your question: (i) the part you add the markers to your map, and (ii) the part you add the click event listener.

Comment: ty very much, solved it. I used the markers array to hide all markers with one button, but did not think i can use it for adding listener. Thank you very much. I am new to stackoverflow, so tell me if i can do anything other to show my appreciation than clicking "this answer is useful". BIG THANKIES